# c# WinForm - Pre-requisite for running Oracle Database Access

Tags: winforms, oracle, oracle11g, c#-3.0

I've a Windows Form c# application which uses Oracle.DatabaseAccess.dll for communicating with oracle database.

After generating a MSI and installing on my laptop everything works great.

However when I try to install the same application on my colleague's laptop the connection doesn't work. It shows incompatible provider.

Could someone please help me out where can I get the pre-requisites for running application that uses oracle database?

I suspect it runs fine on my machine as I've installed oracle express database. But I don't want to install this on all machine where this application needs to be run.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to install the according oracle database driver.

Comment: There are so many, how do I we choose the right one?http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: It really depends on your requirements - I tend to use the package with the smallest installation footprint. It also depends on how you plan to roll out on your target client machines. You'll habe to compare and decide which fits your scenario.

Comment: Still unsure how do I decide driver for 11g vs. 9? Is it based on oracle database you are trying to connect to? Any idea what is XCOPY of ODAC used for?

Comment: XCOPY denotes the driver which doesn't need a setup on the client machine and adheres to the Microsoft concept of "xcopy deployment", meaing you simply copy all components into a folder on the target machine (vs. running a setup registering the software to the installed programs list).